# Rails routes not matching 'new' pattern with RESTFul routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, mongoid, url-routing

I got this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"video_publications", :campaign_id=[...]
```

With this url:

```
/campaigns/514be3834413790249000025/video_publications/new
```

I have this in the routes:

```
resources :campaigns do
   resources :video_publications
end
```

I got the error when I am redirecting to:

```
new_campaign_video_publication_path(@campaign)
```

I am confused, any ideas?

Using:

- Rails 3.2.11
- Mongoid 3.0.23

Comment: I have answered below, but you could paste your `new.html.erb` and `_form.html.erb` code here, just to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not in your `new` path, but in your `show` action.

It is complaining about:

```
:action=>"show", :controller=>"video_publications"
```

In your code change parts of the code for show action to something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', campaign_video_publication_path(@campaign, @publication) %>
```

Comment: Yeah, it was that! Thanks! Kind of confusing this routing error, your are expecting an issue of your routes.rb not your view code.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit :) I am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code in the routes.rb

```
match 'campaigns/:id/video_publications/new' => 'campaigns/video_publications/new',:as => :new_campaign_video_publication
```

Comment: This will not accomplish anything. The routes are defined correctly in the first place. Besides, the code will not work correctly and havy using matchers is inadvisable